# Homeomorphic images of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \Omega  \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be a homeomorphism. If $\Omega$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then how do we show that $\mathbb{R}^n  \backslash \Omega$ is an unbounded set?

Suppose, to the contrary, $\mathbb{R}^n  \backslash \Omega$ is bounded. It is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and hence is compact. $\Omega$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Further, is we show $\Omega$ is closed, using our assumption, we would arrive at a contradiction that $\Omega$ is the empty set.

Any help regarding how to do this?

Other methods would be appreciated too.

Comment: It is not entirely obvious that $\Omega$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I think. I expect it's true, though.

Comment: @JordanPayette, doesn't it follow from the fact that $f$ is an open map and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open in itself?

Comment: @Tanuj This argument is too general to work. Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y \subset X$ with the induced topology. Suppose there exists a homeomorphism $f : X \to Y$. Then $f$ is open and $X$ is open in itself; Is this sufficient to claim that $Y$ is open in $X$? The answer is no: for instance, take $X = [0,1]$ and $Y = [1/4,1/2]$. The particular topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has to come into play. However, the proof is simpler than what I did: $A$ and $C = f(\partial B)$ are disjoint compact sets and can be separated by open sets. The open connected component containing $p$ is in $\Omega$.

Comment: @JordanPayette We know by different means that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Does your argument prove this, by setting $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon x_n=0\}$? I doubt it, but would love to have such a simple proof! My point is that, if $\Omega$ is not open, then relatively open subsets of $\Omega$ need not be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So you have to be very careful when arguing around the topology of $\Omega$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You are perfectly right. I am aware of the subtleties involved in this problem, subtleties behind the insufficiency of Tanuj's proposition. This did not prevent me from over-looking some of these subtleties: I was implicitly assuming a few nontrivial things. I erased my first two erroneous comments, but I leave my reply to Tanuj in spite of the falsity of my 'simpler proof'. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose on the contrary that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega$ is non-empty and bounded. So there exist $p \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega$ and a closed round ball $B$ centred at $p$ which contains $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega$. In other words, $\partial B \subset \Omega$. Let $\iota : S^{n-1} \cong \partial B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the 'inclusion'; This is a continuous map. So $\iota$ is a $(n-1)$-singular cycle. By construction, it is not a boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ p \}$ and *a fortiori* it is not a boundary in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{p\}$.

Since $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \Omega$ is a homeomorphism, $f^{-1} : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined and continuous. Hence, the map $f^{-1} \circ \iota : S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $(n-1)$-singular cycle. Because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible, this cycle is a boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $g : B^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $n$-chain such that $\partial g = f^{-1} \circ \iota$. Then $f \circ g : B^n \to \Omega$ is such that $\partial (f \circ g) = \iota$. This shows that $\iota$ is a boundary in $\Omega$, which yields the contradiction.